# Unable to login as Jenkins user

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Im trying to setup Jenkins for one of my project but get this host key verification failed error.
Now, Im trying to setup a ssh key for my jenkins user but have issues logging as jenkins user.

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

When I try this above command it takes me to

```
bash-4.1$
```

instead of bash user.

Comment: Please clarify more on what you mean or what is wrong with this question? I had been using SO for sometime now and had been posting similar questions.

Comment: It's not about programming.  Stack Overflow is about programming.

Comment: It might be a Server Fault question.

Comment: I just looked at the help files myself and your question *might* sneak in under the heading "tools commonly used for programming" but I still feel like you'll get better results on server fault, since the answer is probably more about "how to configure a Jenkins server" than how do I write code that <insert purpose here>

Comment: Regardless of where the question should be placed, I do not understand it. The command you give is perfectly OK to start a session as the jenkins user. However since you do not specify '-', you will still be located in the same directory as before you issued the command.

Comment: try: sudo su -s /bin/bash - jenkins